# Open lotus notes database using ssl vpn connection

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

i try to open lotus notes database form my personal pc connected by SSL VPN to my company
but when i try to open a database lotus notes retrive me the following message:

This database is currently being used by someone else. In order to share a Notes database, all users must use a domino server instead of a File Server

and i can't access to database...

Someone can help me ?

Comment: no other application is using notes db from my personal pc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you try to open a Notes database on file system which is stored in IBM Notes Domino server's data folder or subfolder. That doesn't work. The Domino server manages those databases and don't let you open it directly. You have to access this database from Notes client opening it on Notes server with menu "File / Open / Lotus Notes Application" and selecting the Domino server.

This error message occurs also when you try to use a personal Notes data directory twice. This happens when you open Notes client from two computers and both are using same Notes data directory on a company server (usually on user's home directory). If this is the case you can copy Notes data directory to somewhere else and link data path in notes.ini to this new directory.

Comment: If i try to open database from File->Database-> Open and write the name of the server of my company or it's ip address notes retrive "Unable to find path to server" error... any ideas ?

Comment: Do you have definied and selected "TCPIP" with driver TCP in "File / Preferences / Notes Ports"?

Comment: if i try to ping server from cmd it respond correctly

Comment: Check Location document at "File / Preferences / Locations" if "Location type" is set to "Local Area Network".

Comment: I create a new connection to server in names.nsf database under Advanced-> Connection "New connection to server" and now it work !

Answer (score 0):

NRPC (the Notes proprietary protocol) uses port 1352, which may be not open in your VPN setting.

From your remote PC, try this :

telnet *serveripaddress* 1352

If telnet fails, see with your network admins to have port 1352 opened.

(on a side note, having the file system of a Domino server shared and remotely accessible is a terrible security practise)